Is there a way to reserve a new row ID in an sqlite3 table?
Question: Is there a way to reserve a new rowid for a table in sqlite3 for later use?
Background: In my sqlite3 database, a capacity has one or more args. So I use the following tables:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS capacity(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
  org INTEGER NOT NULL,
  user INTEGER NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY(user) REFERENCES user(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY(org) REFERENCES org(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS capacity_args(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  capacity INTEGER NOT NULL,
  arg BLOB NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY(capacity) REFERENCES capacity(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
);

The problem with this is that when I insert new records in a transaction, I need to know the capacity Id for the capacity column in capacity_args. Most solutions I've seen suggest SELECT last_insert_rowid(); but this doesn't seem safe within a transaction in a concurrent environment. Using autoincrement has the same problem: After reading an autoincrement primary key, another process might add a capacity before I've added mine. The only safe answer I've found is manage a custom list of ids in a separate table and commit addition and removal accordingly but this does not use sqlite's id allocation mechanism at all.
Isn't there a better solution?

Look at RETURNING

I'm not sure this will work reliably: "While SQLite does guarantee that all database changes will occur before any RETURNING output is emitted, it does not guarantee that the order of individual RETURNING rows will match the order in which those rows were changed in the database. The output order for the RETURNING rows is arbitrary and is not necessarily related to the order in which the rows were processed internally. " There seems to be no guarantee that RETURNING last_insert_rowid(); gives me the right rowid with concurrent writes. Or is this generally guaranteed by sqlite?

Try a SELECT statement on id with referenced row's columns in a WHERE clause instead of last_insert_rowid().

Perhaps consider a TRIGGER on the capacity table that runs after the insert, within the same transaction and effectively as part of the insert.
Perhaps consider the following demo:-
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS capacity_args;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS capacity;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS org;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, username TEXT);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS org (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, orgname TEXT);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS capacity (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
  org INTEGER NOT NULL,
  user INTEGER NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY(user) REFERENCES user(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY(org) REFERENCES org(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS capacity_args(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  capacity INTEGER NOT NULL,
  arg BLOB NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY(capacity) REFERENCES capacity(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
/* load some users and orgs */
INSERT INTO user VALUES (null,'FRED'),(100,'BERT'),(null,'MARY'),(null,'SUE');
INSERT INTO org VALUES (1000,'ORG1'),(null,'ORG2'),(-100,'ORG3'),(null,'ORG4');

/* THE TRIGGER */
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS ca_after_insert AFTER INSERT ON capacity 
    BEGIN
        /* When the TRIGGER is triggered then do this */
        /* note that for an AFTER INSERT you can refer to the columns using a schema name of new, they will hold the respective values as inserted */
        /* so the capacity column of the capacity_args table will contain the id of the inserted capacity i.e. new.id */
        INSERT INTO capacity_args VALUES (null,new.id,hex(zeroblob(10))||new.name);
    END
;
INSERT INTO capacity VALUES
    (500,'C1',1001,100),
    (null,'C2',1002,1),
    (null,'C3',1000,101),
    (null,'C4',-100,102)
    
;
/* Output the resultant data */
SELECT * FROM capacity JOIN user ON user.id=capacity.user JOIN org ON org.id=capacity.org JOIN capacity_args ON capacity_args.capacity=capacity.id;
/* Cleanup the demo environment */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS capacity_args;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS capacity;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS org;


The value for the arg column could be whatever suits, the value inserted in the demo contains two concatenated values x0000000000 and the name of the capacity thus making 3 values that can be used to reflect the reserved status (0000000000) and the respective related capacity (perhaps overkill)

When run the above demo outputs:-


i.e. the highlighted block are the columns from the capacity_args table.

The following is an example of UPDATEing the reserved rows albeit it  highly unlikely to be of use as the arg value is just a random blob that is the same length as the respective capacity id.
So:-
UPDATE capacity_args SET arg = randomblob((SELECT id FROM capacity WHERE capacity.id = capacity)) WHERE arg LIKE hex(zeroblob(10))||(SELECT name FROM capacity WHERE capacity.id= capacity);
SELECT *, length(arg) FROM capacity JOIN user ON user.id=capacity.user JOIN org ON org.id=capacity.org JOIN capacity_args ON capacity_args.capacity=capacity.id;


The update will only update the reserved rows as per the WHERE clause. Obviously this only suits the demo.

Results in the output after the UPDATE being:-


the last value being the length of the blob which is according to the parent capacity's id column.

Of course if there is just the single capacity_arg row per capacity, then perhaps consider the single capacity table having the arg column.
If you wanted to reserve more that 1 row per capacity you could insert a fixed number e.g. the following triggered INSERT  would reserve 5 rows per inserted capacity:-
.... BEGIN INSERT INTO capacity_args VALUES (null,new.id,hex(zeroblob(10))||new.name),(null,new.id,hex(zeroblob(10))||new.name),(null,new.id,hex(zeroblob(10))||new.name),(null,new.id,hex(zeroblob(10))||new.name),(null,new.id,hex(zeroblob(10))||new.name); END;

The output would then be like:-


i.e. 5 reserved rows per capacity inserted.


Additional

Re the comment

The problem is that the data in the args need to be custom and the trigger cannot be parameterized (or can it?). But I'll investigate the possible use of triggers further.


Correct you cannot pass parameters to the TRIGGER.

However, you could have the TRIGGER extract/utilise data that could be passed as a parameter when inserting the parent capacity.

However as the arg/value has a 1-1 relationship between the capacity and capactiy_args table then there is no need to have a second (capacity_args) table.


So ignoring the above point  in regard to having a single table perhaps consider the following deviation to the demo above


:-
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS capacity_args;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS capacity;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS org;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, username TEXT);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS org (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, orgname TEXT);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS capacity (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
  org INTEGER NOT NULL,
  user INTEGER NOT NULL,
  /* column ADDED for deviation to enable the arg value to be applied to the capacity_args. */
  /* Noting that this affirms the no need for a 1-1 related table (capacity_args). */
  args_for_reserved BLOB, 
  FOREIGN KEY(user) REFERENCES user(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY(org) REFERENCES org(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS capacity_args(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  capacity INTEGER NOT NULL,
  arg BLOB NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY(capacity) REFERENCES capacity(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
/* load some users and orgs */
INSERT INTO user VALUES (null,'FRED'),(100,'BERT'),(null,'MARY'),(null,'SUE');
INSERT INTO org VALUES (1000,'ORG1'),(null,'ORG2'),(-100,'ORG3'),(null,'ORG4');

/* THE TRIGGER */
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS ca_after_insert AFTER INSERT ON capacity 
    BEGIN
        /* When the TRIGGER is triggered then do this */
        /* note that for an AFTER INSERT you can refer to the columns using a schema name of new, they will hold the respective values as inserted */
        /* so the capacity column of the capacity_args table will contain the id of the inserted capacity i.e. new.id */
        INSERT INTO capacity_args VALUES (null,new.id,new.args_for_reserved /*<<<<<<<<<< ADDED for deviation; value (args) copied from capacity table*/);
        /* ADDED for deviation; Optional to clear the column data from the capacity table, but as can be seen done when inserting the data*/
        UPDATE capacity SET args_for_reserved = zeroblob(0) WHERE id=new.id;
    END
;
INSERT INTO capacity VALUES
    (500,'C1',1001,100,x'00ff11ee' /* THE arg value which could be a bound parameter*/),
    (null,'C2',1002,1,x'ee11ff00'),
    (null,'C3',1000,101,x'0102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f'),
    (null,'C4',-100,102,x'0f0e0d0c0b0a090807060504030201')
    
;
/* Output the resultant data */
SELECT *, hex(arg) AS arg_as_hex_for_demo /*<<<<<<<< ADDED for deviation to show arg as hex value*/ FROM capacity JOIN user ON user.id=capacity.user JOIN org ON org.id=capacity.org JOIN capacity_args ON capacity_args.capacity=capacity.id;
/* Cleanup the demo environment */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS capacity_args;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS capacity;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS org;


as can be seen there is no need for the capacity_args table, the args could simply be kept in the capacity table.

obviously if there are multiple args per capacity and thus separate rows and therefore that capacity_args is in fact a 1-Many type relationship then the TRIGGER would either be impractical or more complicated.


also note that the TRIGGER can undertake multiple actions within the BEGIN .... END (in the above it does an INSERT and then an UPDATE). However, there are limitations e.g. CTE's (and therefore recursion) are not supported.

The output from the final SELECT, i.e. after the TRIGGER has done it's work, would be:-


each highlighted block is one of the 4 tables; the first being the capacity table, the 2nd the user table, the 3rd the org table and the 4th the capacity_args table
the blue lines indicate relationships
as can be seen, the capacity_args table has the value as passed

noting that the args_for_reserved (additional column) has been cleared and thus will consume little space/storage.

However, the additional, apparently unnecessary, capacity_args table will always require more space/storage than if the arg value were stored in the capacity table.

i.e. in addition to the underlying value of the arg itself the additional table will have the overheads of the additional index (PRIMARY KEY), the value of the primary key, and the value of the parent.
actually obtaining the related value, the arg, will invariably incur some processing overheads








It works for this use case but I'm reluctant to mark it as a general answer. The problem is that the data in the args need to be custom and the trigger cannot be parameterized (or can it?). But I'll investigate the possible use of triggers further. Thanks a lot!
